# JS Canvas: lineTo()

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to Javascript!

How do I assign a variable to the current xy coordinates, so I can use relative positions to draw lines? Trying to do etch-a-sketch with keyboard. Up, down, left, right arrow keys... with JS, CSS, and HTML.

Thanks!

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyd);
function keyd(event) {
  var etchMain = document.getElementById('etchMain');
  var etchContext = etchMain.getContext('2d');
  var key = event.keyCode;
  **var etchContextPositionX;
  var etchContextPositionY;**
  if (key == 37) {
    // left arrow
    if (etchMain.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
      etchContext.beginPath();
      etchContext.moveTo(etchMain.width / 2, etchMain.height / 2);
      // arrow specific drawing goes here
    }
    else {

    }
  }
  if (key == 38) {
    // up arrow
    if (etchMain.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
      etchContext.beginPath();
      etchContext.moveTo(etchMain.width / 2, etchMain.height / 2);
      // arrow specific drawing goes here
    }
    else {

    }
  }
  if (key == 39) {
    // right arrow
    if (etchMain.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
      etchContext.beginPath();
      etchContext.moveTo(etchMain.width / 2, etchMain.height / 2);
      // arrow specific drawing goes here
    }
    else {

    }
  }
  if (key == 39) {
    // down arrow
    if (etchMain.toDataURL() == document.getElementById('blank').toDataURL()) {
      etchContext.beginPath();
      etchContext.moveTo(etchMain.width / 2, etchMain.height / 2);
      // arrow specific drawing goes here

    }
    else {

    }
  }
}
function clearCanvas() {
  var etchMain = document.getElementById('etchMain');
  var etchContext = etchMain.getContext('2d');
  etchContext.clearRect(0, 0, etchMain.width, etchMain.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i implemented a really basic idea of what you're talking about just because it sounded kind of fun. hit *run snippet*, then click on the canvas box to give that frame focus. the event handler will prevent window scrolling and instead use the arrow inputs to increment or decrement *x* and *y* and draw from there or you can hit space bar to clear the canvas!

the bit of design you were missing was storing *x* and *y* outside of the event handler and using the difference between the previous state of *x* and *y* to draw your canvas lines:

```js
var pos = {
  x: 50,
  y: 50,
}

var etchMain = document.getElementById('etchMain');
var etchContext = etchMain.getContext('2d');

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if(e.keyCode === 32) {
    clearCanvas();
  } else {

    etchContext.beginPath();
    etchContext.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);

    switch (e.keyCode) {
      //left arrow
      case 37:
        pos.x--;
        break;
      //up arrow
      case 38:
        pos.y--;
        break;
      //right arrow
      case 39:
        pos.x++;
        break;
      //down arrow
      case 40:
        pos.y++;
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }

      etchContext.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
      etchContext.stroke();
    }
});

function clearCanvas() {
  etchContext.clearRect(0, 0, etchMain.width, etchMain.height);
}
```

```css
#etchMain {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="etchMain" height="100" width="100" />
```